# How to retrieve a session-scoped bean inside AuthenticationSuccessHandler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, session-scope

I have a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

What I want to do is to set some session data within onAuthenticationSuccess method.

To store session data I want to use a session-scoped bean, which works fine within any controller.

But if I try to retrieve it within onAuthenticationSuccess method, I get an exception:

> Error creating bean with name
>   'scopedTarget.sessionData': Scope
>   'session' is not active for the
>   current thread;

My code is:

```
WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(request.getServletContext());
SessionData sessionData = context.getBean(SessionData.class);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to declare a listener that exposes state necessary to implement session scope:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

By default that state is exposed by `DispatcherServlet`, so it's not available before request enters `DispatcherServlet` (e.g. in Spring Security filters).